# is it worth to avoid modulus operator in js

Tags: javascript, performance

i'm making a game in javascript and this function is suposed to be called by each instance inside the game

```js
draw : function( ctx, { cell } ){
            this.image.index += this.image.speed; while( this.image.index >= this.current.image.n ) this.image.index -= this.current.image.n;
            //this.image.index = (this.image.index + this.image.speed) % this.current.image.n; 

            this.current?.draw( ctx , Math.floor(this.image.index), this.x * cell.x, this.y * cell.y );
        }
```

i read that modulus operator (`%`) is really slow and i want to avoid calling it unnecesarily each frame so i came up with this `while` solution. But now there are more operations being executed and i don't know if this is efficient.

i would like to know if i should use the modulus or the `while` aproach.
Also, i don't how `>=` operator will affect performance, so if someone knows it would also be a great help.

Comment: The modulus operator will not negative affect this codes supposed performance. *It can even be “faster” as it avoids logical branches and other work, including the potential for many loops*. If you really care to correct and/or validate this hypothesis, create some (suitable) benchmarks and test across browsers/environments.

Comment: When you hear that something is slow, ask: 1) slow for what, 2) slow comparing to what. Modulus operator will certainly be hundreds times faster than a manual loop, and certainly won't be a bottleneck in a JS game.

Comment: Now that you mention i should test which is faster, could you also provide a link to a source that explains how to perform a benchmark, i'm relatively new and i don't know how these comparisons are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case it is definitely **not worth to avoid the modulus operator**.

As an experienced developer I have a hard time understanding your code by just looking at it. Readable code is (almost) always more important than optimized code.

In the spirit of @NPE's answer to [Is it better to avoid using the mod operator when possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596318/is-it-better-to-avoid-using-the-mod-operator-when-possible)
I strongly suggest you to use the version that is easier to read. Once you have a working product you can start to optimize. Use performance analysis tools to find out where your performance bottlenecks are. Most of the time you will find the culprits are nested loops, recursion, values that can be stored instead of recalculating them, slow API calls (DOM, fs, db, network), ...) Optimizing operators is probably not worth it.

Btw. I am sure that the optional chaining operator (`this.current?.draw(`) has a stronger impact on the performance than the modulo operator.